# How can i change how an array prints in console?

Tags: angular, kotlin, axios, ktor

I've designed an api(axios) in typescript(angular), that sends an array of strings(Logs) from the U.I to the server backend(ktor). Everything works apart from the way the data is displayed in the server.

The data comes out as

```
  {data, data, data}
```

but i want it to come out as

```
{data
data
data}
```

Comment: `{data, data, data}` this looks like an object rather than an array. Show how you're currently displaying the logs.

Comment: Also could you please share information about the HTTP request you make from UI?